# How can i add info to url in php?

Tags: php, post, get

I have a site in html and in a page, I have buttons to take the visitors to dj's profiles.

Each button takes the visitor to a different dj profile. 
I create a page in html that goes to a XML document to get the information of the dj. So, my question is, how can i add at the link of php page, the name of dj, so he can stay with a personal link?

I tried the get properties but i need to have the post too, in order for PHP to take the information of that dj.

The html of djspace.html page have this:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post"  action="allProfiles.php">
  <input type="submit" name="dj_name" value="Blowdrop"/> 
</form>
...
<form name="form" id="form" method="post"  action="allProfiles.php">
  <input type="submit" name="dj_name" value="Psychokiller"/> 
</form>
```

and then my allprofiles.php page:

```
<?php
  $counter = 0;
  $dj_name = ($_POST['dj_name']);
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("Profiles.xml");

  foreach ($xml as $newprofile){
    if($xml->newprofile[$counter]->Anome == $dj_name){
      $Anome           = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->Anome;
      $nacionalidade   = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->nacionalidade;
      $naturalidade    = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->naturalidade;
      $residencia      = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->residencia;
      $emprego         = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->emprego;
      $generos         = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->generos;
      $disponibilidade = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->disponibilidade;
      $partilha        = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->partilha;
      $sitios          = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->sitios;
      $tempo           = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->tempo;
      $editora         = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->editora;
      $promotora       = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->promotora;
      $influencias     = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->influencias;
      $fblink          = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->fb;
      $scloud          = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->scloud;
      $mail            = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->email;
      $img             = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->foto;
    }
  $counter = $counter + 1;
}

?>
```

I can get all the information but I if i apply the get, I can't.

Obviously if you go directly to php page, you get none information.
http://roundhillevents.com/allProfiles.php

However go in this link, and then, dj's, dj space, and then click in the one you want to see the information.

Comment: you're doing post for simple data retrieval. why not use GET, e.g. `<a href="profile.php?dj_name=Blowdrop">Blowdrop</a>`?

Comment: Do extract($xml->newprofile[$counter]); this code is unreadable...^^

Comment: Sorry bwoebi, i don't get your point. Where i do that?

Answer (score 1):

As @Marc B suggested, use link instead of form with button.

If you want to keep using buttons for whatever reason, change `method="post"` to `method="get"`. Then browser adds the dj reference to the URL of the page for you.

Of couse, you then need to use `$_GET['dj_name'])` instead of `$_POST['dj_name']` in your PHP code. This is for both cases, buttons with `GET` method and links.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are using $_POST in php. try using $_REQUEST or $_GET global variable instead of $_POST

**try this**

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$dj_name = ($_REQUEST['dj_name']);
$xml = simplexml_load_file("Profiles.xml");
foreach ($xml as $newprofile){
if($xml->newprofile[$counter]->Anome == $dj_name){
$Anome = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->Anome;
$nacionalidade = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->nacionalidade;
$naturalidade = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->naturalidade;
$residencia = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->residencia;
$emprego = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->emprego;
$generos = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->generos;
$disponibilidade = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->disponibilidade;
$partilha = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->partilha;
$sitios = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->sitios;
$tempo = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->tempo;
$editora = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->editora;
$promotora = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->promotora;
$influencias = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->influencias;
$fblink = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->fb;
$scloud = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->scloud;
$mail = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->email;
$img = $xml->newprofile[$counter]->foto;
}
$counter = $counter + 1;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much all of you. I fixed 2 problems with your help.
I use the link instead of use the button and using the REQUEST i can easyli guet all the information. I'm greatfull. Thank you all.